# python statsmodels.predict does not work

Tags: python, statsmodels

```
x=range(100)
y=sin(x)
result=sm.OLS(x,y).fit()
result.predict(x)
```

Gives:

```
ValueError: matrices are not aligned
```

This is very simple code, not sure why it's not working? I searched lots of forums but could not find exact solution.

Answer (score 1):

quick answer:

I think you want x and y reversed `result=sm.OLS(y, x).fit()` 
The dependent variable (`y`) comes first, and then the array of explanatory variables (`x`).

The call to predict works with statsmodels master, but maybe you need a 2-D `x` in an older version:

`result.predict(x[:,None])`

to make the explanatory variable into a column_array. I don't remember when this was changed for 1-D x.)

Note also, that there is no constant/intercept added automatically when we don't use the formula interface.

The predict for the sample or training data can also be accessed through `results.fittedvalues`.